# How can I come back to the calling point

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a Controller in Spring MVC. As per a requirement, I have to call a jsp from a point and after some logic in jsp, I need to come back from jsp to the same calling point in Controller. Please let me know if this is possible in Spring Mvc.

Comment: Not really, no, cannot imagine why that is mandatory though...

Comment: I am converting Spring webflow to mvc. Its possible in webflow, to call a jsp and based on the event ids the jsp returns, I will call other view states or action states. Need to convert it to MVC

Comment: Which will require rewriting the parts that use flows, to no longer use flows :)  Or just re-implementing the feature yourself I guess.